# .NET MAUI on iOS: Image is not displayed in the list cell

Tags: ios, maui

In my mobile application, there's declared a list with images:

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding PhotosCollection}" 
          SelectionMode="Single" 
          VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPhotoDocument}">
          
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <ViewCell>
            <Grid Margin="4">

               <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                  <RowDefinition Height="64" />
                  <RowDefinition Height="*" />
               </Grid.RowDefinitions>

               <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
               </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

               <Image Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                      Grid.Column="0" 
                      Source="{Binding ThumbnailImageSource}" 
                      HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                      VerticalOptions="Center" 
                      Aspect="AspectFit" />
                      
               <Label Grid.Column="1" 
                      Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                      Text="{Binding Description}" 
                      FontAttributes="Bold" 
                      HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                      VerticalOptions="Center" 
                      HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" 
                      VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
            </Grid>
         </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

This list works perfectly on Android platform and displays images along with descriptions. But on iOS platform thumbnails are not being displayed. Only descriptions are shown.

How can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this issue to get mobile app working as well as on iOS and on Android, I used `ImageCell` instead of `Image` and `Label` tags in the `ListView` data template declaration.

```xml
<ListView 
    ItemsSource="{Binding PhotosCollection}"
    SelectionMode="Single"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPhotoDocument}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ImageCell
                    ImageSource="{Binding ThumbnailImageSource}"
                    Text="{Binding Description}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: I have read a lot of posts, that listview is buggy. Try the same with collectionview.